# How do I correctly make an HTTP request to the Twitter API?

Tags: twitter, postman, httprequest

I am using postman to make an HTTP request to the Twitter API but I am unable to get the correct response in Postman. I am making a GET request to;

```
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter
```

and I have selected Authorisation Type as Bearer. I have pasted in the Twitter Bearer Token from my Twitter Developer Account but I get the following response from Postman when I click on Send;

```
<html>\n

<head>\n
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />\n<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=twitter'. Reason:
        <pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman does not support streaming responses, so accessing this endpoint will not work. Also, for v1.1, you need to use OAuth 1.0A to access the streaming API. Additionally, that endpoint requires HTTP POST https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter

Comment: Thanks. So can I use AlamoFire in an iOS app to receive streaming responses?

Comment: I think it might work, but I have not tried it, so I do not know.

Comment: AAAAGHH! I'm stuck! Help!

Comment: Can you share the code you’re trying to use and the specific error? It is difficult to help with “I’m stuck”. Thanks.